# Assign people to optimal groups given preferences of who each person wants to be in a group with

Tags: optimization, np-complete, np-hard, hungarian-algorithm

Create groups of size 6 given 100 individuals, each of whom has specified their top 10 other people they would desire to be in a group with.

Ideally I would like to do this in Python.

I have looked around online and encountered terms I wasn't aware of before, and now I'm pretty lost. I'm aware that this is an NP-complete or NP-hard problem, although I'm not entirely sure what that means. It also seems like a combinatorial optimization problem, but again- these are just terms I barely have any understanding of from researching this problem.

I tried using networkx and created a directed network, but that is about it. None of the community functions or clique functions apply to directed graphs, only non-directional.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, you should probably ask your teacher some of these questions.

Comment: As for your [hungarian-algorithm] tag, the Hungarian algorithm can find *pairs*, but not groups larger than that, so you won't be able to use that for this.